# Adding Volume to docker container's /app Issue

Tags: docker

I am having trouble creating a volume that maps to the directory "/app" in my container

This is basically so when I update the code I don't need to build the container again

This is my docker file

```
# stage 1 
FROM node:latest as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build --prod

# stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/my-first-app /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I use this command to run the container

```
docker run -d -p 100:80/tcp -v ${PWD}/app:/app docker-testing:v1
```

and no volume gets linked to it.

However, if I were to do this

```
docker run -d -p 100:80/tcp -v ${PWD} docker-testing:v1
```

I do get a volume at least

[image]

Anything obvious that I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Deleted my comment as it didnt take into consideration that the image build is a multistage build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `${PWD}:/app:/app` should be `${PWD}/app:/app`.

If you explode `${PWD}`, you'd obtain something like `/home/user/src/thingy:/app:/app` which does not make much sense.

EDIT:
I'd suggest using `docker-compose` to avoid this kind of issues (it also simplify a lot the commands to start up docker).

In your case the docker-compose.yml would look like this:

docker run  -d -p 100:80/tcp -v ${PWD}:/app:/app docker-testing:v1

```
version: "3"
services:
  doctesting:
    build: .
    image: docker-testing:v1
    volumes:
      - "./app:/app"  
    ports:
      - "100:80"
```

I didn't really test if it works, there might be typos...

Comment: Thanks for introducing to the compose file.